# Magento2 Overriding template with plugin for Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Invoice\Items gives error with renderer list not found

Tags: magento2, invoice, template-override

I am receiving error when I use plugin to modify Invoice Items template.

```
Exception #0 (RuntimeException): Renderer list for block "sales.order.invoice" is not defined
```

This seems like a weird bug, I tried to add sequence in module.xml for Magento_Sales, but still gives the error.

Is there a better way to override this template file?

In my \Vendor\Module\etc\frontend\di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Invoice\Items">
    <plugin name="vendor_module_sales_order_invoice_items" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Sales\Order\Invoice\Items" />
</type>
```

My plugin file \Vendor\Module\Plugin\Sales\Order\Invoice\Items.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Sales\Order\Invoice;

use Vendor\Module\Helper\Data as Helper;

class Items
{
    protected $_helper;

    public function __construct(
        Helper $_helper
    ) 
    {
        $this->_helper = $_helper;
    }

    public function beforeToHtml($subject)
    {
        if(!$this->_helper->isEnabled()) {
            return;
        }

        $subject->setTemplate("Vendor_Module::sales/order/invoice/items.phtml");
        return;
    }
}
```

Has anyone else encountered this? And is there a better way to workaround this problem? 
I am using Magento version 2.3.1.

Answer (score 1):

The best method of changes the template of a **Block class** `Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Invoice\Items` using plugin that `getTemplate`.

#### Here plugin code

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Sales\Order\Invoice;

use Vendor\Module\Helper\Data as Helper;

class Items
{
    protected $_helper;

    public function __construct(
        Helper $_helper
    ) 
    {
        $this->_helper = $_helper;
    }

    public function afterGetTemplate(
        \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Invoice\Items $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        if(!$this->_helper->isEnabled()) {
          return $result;  
        }

        return "Vendor_Module::sales/order/invoice/items.phtml";
    }   
}
```

#### If you want to continue with your beforeToHtml then  changes return tpye

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Sales\Order\Invoice;

use Vendor\Module\Helper\Data as Helper;

class Items
{
    protected $_helper;

    public function __construct(
        Helper $_helper
    ) 
    {
        $this->_helper = $_helper;
    }

    public function beforeToHtml($subject)
    {
        if(!$this->_helper->isEnabled()) {
            return [];
        }

        $subject->setTemplate("Vendor_Module::sales/order/invoice/items.phtml");
        $return [];
    }

}
```

Comment: So @Amit Bera, just out of curiosity, is there any other way to override a template other than using a plugin? I always thought the only way to do it was to override the corresponding layout file or recreating the template in the <theme_dir>. 
So which is recommended way to do?
Would you please shed some light on that. It would be very helpful to me. Thanks in, advance.

Comment: @Amit Bera I agree both those solutions SHOULD be working, but neither of them do, still returns the same error. 
Exception #0 (RuntimeException): Renderer list for block "sales.order.invoice" is not defined

Answer (score 0):

You can try different approach

Create new layout file:

```
Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/sales_order_invoice.xml
```

with content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="invoice_items">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::order/invoice/items.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Create new .phtml file

```
Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/order/invoice/items.phtml
```

with content that you wanna customize or copied from default Magento.